# Need advice pset4 recover. Tried for a week and still getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, cs50, recover

Output:

```
:( recovers 000.jpg correctly
    failed to execute program due to segmentation fault
:( recovers middle images correctly
    failed to execute program due to segmentation fault
:( recovers 049.jpg correctly
    failed to execute program due to segmentation fault
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) //to make sure that accept exactly one command-line argument
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r"); //open the file card.raw and creating a new file called f in read format
    if (infile == NULL)//if file cannot open then print below if can open just continue
    {
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
        return 2;
    }

    FILE *img; //img is the output
    int jpeg_counter = 0; // to count the no. of jpeg files
    uint8_t buffer[512]; //cos 512 bytes and the buffer is the temporary storage 
    char filename[8];


    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, infile) == 512)
        //continue doing this loop if the while conditions are true. to repeat until end of card.like while the file you reading is true,
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            //removing last 4 bits of the 8 bits, only looking at they first 4 which is e. setting all to 0
            //if start of new jpeg with above conditions 
        {
            if (jpeg_counter != 0) // telling them that you previously found jpeg
            {
                fclose(img);//else if never find before, tell them now that you have found it by making it true
            }

            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", jpeg_counter); //%03i means print an integer with 3 digits
            jpeg_counter ++;
            img = fopen(filename , "w"); //open the new file w for writting 
            if (img == NULL) //see if can remove this
                return 3;
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);// writing new output file

        }    
        if (jpeg_counter != 0)
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);
    } 
    fclose(infile);
    fclose(img);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this code meant to do? Have you tried using your debugger to identify where the segfault occurs? SO isn't just a black box where you put in code and get a solution for it. Evidence of effort and context are expected.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want to read 1 element of 512 bytes via `fread` what is the expected return value? What does the function return for you? Did you check in a debugger?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the segfault with valgrind or address sanitizer?

Comment: You should also run the code in a debugger to check if your logic is somehow related to your problem. Do you handle first and follow up blocks of an image? Only first block?

Comment: `fclose(img);` What will happen if you cannot read from the input file at all?

Comment: "Tried for a week and still ..." Just out of curiosity: Do they teach anything related to how to find such issues in those courses?

Comment: I'm looking at my code from a year or so ago and it isn't that different. As @Gerhardh said your check for 512 should be a check for 1, and I'd bet the crash is because of `fclose(img)` without checking to see if it is NULL first.

Comment: @RetiredNinja checking if `img==NULL` before closing won't help as `img` is unitialized.

Comment: @Gerhardh Right, that's something that needs to be done too. It was in my code but I didn't scroll up to verify in theirs.

Comment: thanks for the help guys. so ive removed the == 512 in while and the segmentation fault is resolved! YAY! ive removed the img == null as well and it passed check50. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the segfault is cased by `fclose(img)` and `img` is an invalid FILE pointer.  The problem is your while loop condition is never true and the loop is never taken.  Your `fread` will never return 512, it returns 1 on a success read. I have fixed the loop condition for you and added some `printf`s to print out more information so you have a better understanding of what happens.  Here is a [link](https://cee.studio/?bucket=200609-bSc&name=recover) of the fixed code in our cloud IDE, you can use it to debug segfault in the future.